# Rails with activeadmin and devise - signed_in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I have installed devise and activeadmin. When i login to activeadmin rails thinks that im also signed_in as a user on page but with no current_user value. 
When i go on some pages without login as user (with logged on activeadmin) statement:

```
<% if signed_in? %>
```

is true and rails try to run script in it. How can i tell rails that activeadmin users isnt current_user for whole site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should tell the signed_in? method which user to look at:

on regular user pages where you do not want to be considered as signed in when you're signed in as an admin, you may want to replace

```
    <% if signed_in? %>
```

by

```
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
```

where user is the name of your Devise resource (if you have named it differently, replace user by the actual name (ex: if your Devise user model is EndUser, your should put end_user_signed_in?)

Comment: I've diligently tried to understand Devise but I just can't read it. What does that method even check? Does it check a cookie that gets set when you sign in?

Comment: Why replacing signed_in? with user_signed_in?. Because I am having trouble with signed_in? method, link to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046820/difference-between-signed-inuser-and-user-signed-in